# Bounty tooltip pluralization

Tags: bug, status-declined, bounties, plurals

> [image: This answer has been awarded bounties worth 500 reputation by nicael]

There was only [1 bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/240417/revisions) awarded to me. Also, "by" should be "from".

Comment: Oh, you just don't know, I can award empty bounties. Don't worry, nothing wrong there ;) Anyway, easy fix: award one more bounty there.

Comment: Disagree with the by/from part. "Awarded by" is correct.

Comment: @Behaviour It sounds better in my mind. "This has been awarded a bounty from nicael".

Comment: No, "by" is better.

Comment: … ok, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, localization - when we only had to deal with English, the tooltip used to have the count as part of the awarding user list, as we could just concat everything together and easily pluralize nouns.

Now, our translators need to know exactly how many user names could be considered, so we have to have translatable strings with all the user name placeholder permutations, e.g.

```
case 0: return _s("This answer has been awarded bounties worth $bountyAmount$ reputation", hash);
case 1: return _s("This answer has been awarded bounties worth $bountyAmount$ reputation by $user1$", hash);
case 2: return _s("This answer has been awarded bounties worth $bountyAmount$ reputation by $user1$ and $user2$", hash);
case 3: return _s("This answer has been awarded bounties worth $bountyAmount$ reputation by $user1$, $user2$ and $user3$", hash);
```

By adding the count in there for bounties, the translators would have to translate for the singular and plural forms (and I don't know all the rules for the languages we're targeting), and things get even more out of hand.

We decided that showing who did the awarding was more important than exactly how many bounties were awarded, as that can be inferred from the user names.

Comment: So when an answer gets four or more bounties, no tooltip is displayed?

Comment: *feels like ur code is mess*

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, that code has a default case that handles > 5, I was just too embarrassed to post it all.

Comment: @bjb568 there's no *feels* to it - it *is* a mess there!  Thankfully, there's only a few places we had to do this.